# How to access the status code when axios ajax call fails

Tags: ajax, reactjs, react-redux, axios, http-status-codes

In our project we are using Axios middleware in order to make an Ajax call and  in order to have consistent Action types, we are using FSA(Flux Standard Action) for the data structure. For example our Actions and Reducer looks as below

```
//Action
 import { createAction } from "typesafe-actions";

 export const GET_USER = "GET_USER";

 // GET_USER_SUCCESS and GET_USER_FAILURE are automatically triggered from the axios 
    middleware
export const userActions = {
    getUser: createAction(GET_USER, () => ({
        type: GET_USER,
        payload: {
        request: {
            url: "/username",
        },
    },
  })),
getUserSuccess: createAction("GET_USER_SUCCESS", (data: string) => ({
    type: "GET_USER_SUCCESS",
    payload: {
        data: data // put returned data type here name: "nothing",},
    },
})),
getUserFailure: createAction("GET_USER_FAILURE"),
};

//Redux
import { RootAction } from "../actions/RootAction";
import { userActions } from "../actions/UserActions";
import { getType } from "typesafe-actions";

export const userReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action: RootAction): UserState => 
{
    switch (action.type) {
        case getType(userActions.getUserSuccess): {
            return {
                ...state,
                username: action.payload.data,
            };
        }
    default:
        return state;
    }
};
```

Now in case of call failure I could like to access the status code from the below
[image]

Need help in how to access the status code in the action or reducer or anywhere in the application.

Comment: Have tried JSON.stringify(err); do you see what you get in the error? Or err.response.status?

Comment: I could see the status code in the response in case of 500 error  but in case of success (ex: 200 ) or other errors such as 404 errors I am not getting the status code in response and just seeing the Json response  in case of Success or no response at all in case of 4XX errors. So I would like to access the status code from the Header for some other functionality.

Comment: You can get status code directly with error.response.status

Comment: where exactly can I use this in the above example. I mean is it Actions or Reducers

Comment: In getUserFailure action. You can get the status code

Answer (score 0):

You can create an error handling function in your actions file and use it to dispatch an action with error details. Then just put this function in every *catch* statement and thus access an error anywhere in the app. An example implementation would look like this (redux thunk approach):

Fetching data

```
export function fetchData() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const { data: payload } = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/psosts');
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_DATA,
        payload
      })
    } catch (error) { throwError(error, dispatch) }
  }
}
```

Handling error

```
function throwError(error, dispatch) {
  const { status, statusText } = error.response;
  dispatch({
    type: THROW_ERROR,
    payload: { status, content: statusText }
  })
}
```

And a reducer for that is just like any other reducer ;)